# Timeout deploying function to Azure using Quarkus

Tags: azure-functions, quarkus

I just implemented an endpoint using Quarkus and I am trying to deploy it to Azure using the maven plugin as follows:

```
mvn clean install azure-functions:deploy
```

Unfortuntaly, I am getting time-out issues, I am wondering if there is a way to increment this time-out somehow. This is how the stack trace looks like:

```
[INFO] Authenticate with Azure CLI 2.0
[INFO] The specified function app does not exist. Creating a new function app...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:40 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-15T10:47:07-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project time-tracker-az-functions: Requested feature is not available in resource group XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX. Please try using a different resource group or create a new one.: OnError while emitting onNext value: retrofit2.Response.class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates for Azure Functions deployment descriptors (`host.json`, `function.json`) are within the `azure-config` directory. Edit them as you need to. Rerun the build when you are ready.

Add the following code into `host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://quarkus.io/guides/azure-functions-http).